# Css codes for borders & slider size

Tags: html, css, slider, border

need help with css codes for a border above and below the header like this website : http://www.simpsonmagazine.cc/ . I also want to change the slider height for my site : http://www.etctaylors.com/

CSS codes used so far :

```
/*
Theme Name:   Sight Child
Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-fourteen-child/
Description:  Twenty Fourteen Child Theme
Author:       John Doe
Author URI:   http://example.com
Template:     Sight
Version:      1.0.0
Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, 
accessibility-ready
Text Domain:  sight-child
*/
/* =Theme customization starts here
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
.main-navigation {
border-bottom: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 3px;
}

.main-navigation li {
text-indent: 5px;
}

.main-navigation ul {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100%;
}

.main-navigation li {
border: none;
}

.main-navigation {
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
width: 100%;
}

.main-navigation li:hover > a, .main-navigation ul ul :hover > a, 
.main-navigation ul ul a:hover {
color: black !important;
text-decoration: none;
}

.main-navigation ul ul, .main-navigation ul li:hover {
background: none;
}

.main-navigation ul ul {
background: none;
}

.main-navigation ul ul a {
color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Do you want that border style around your menu?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply :) i want something like the site: http://www.simpsonmagazine.cc/
its two lines above the header and two lines below.
I am using sight theme :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it will work, I tried it on firebug
[image]

```
.site-header{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        border-top: 1px solid #000000;
        height: 240px;
        padding: 3px 0 3px 0;
        position: relative;
    }

    .site-header:before {
        content: '';
        border-top: 5px solid #000;
        width:100%;
        position: absolute;
        left:0;
        top: 1px;
    }

    .site-header:after {
        content: '';
        border-top: 5px solid #000;
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        left:0;
        bottom:1px;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah this worked great :D I just need another line inside those borders :)

Comment: Done update with edited code, insted of "solid" place it as "double"

Comment: cool but i need to change the thickness of the inner line though :( sorry for the trouble. they keep changing together

Comment: wait for a 5 mins I will give you the answer

Answer (score 0):

use this for border like the mentioned site  to your header css

**markup**

```
 <div id="top">
    <div id="hwrap">
    </div>
    </div>
```

you should include your header contents inside `hwrap` div

**css**

```
  #top {
        width: 940px;
        float: left;
        border-bottom: 5px solid #222;
        border-top: 5px solid #222;
        padding-top: 1px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 1px;
        }
        #hwrap {
        width: 940px;
        float: left;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
        border-top: 1px solid #222;
        padding-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q9e9kug5/)

for changing the slider height in your site

```
  .featured-post {
background: #ffea97;
height:600px;  // or your prefered vaklue
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply :) but i just tried it and its not changing anything :(

Comment: still no changes :( is there something wrong with the setup of my child theme?

Comment: @RaianMahmud: you should include your header contents inside hwrap div

Comment: I dont know what to put inside? is it the url of the header replace it with the hwrap?

Comment: @RaianMahmud:no,you should put the html of the header completely inside the opening and closing of hrwap div

Answer (score 0):

To add a border to your navigation, you can use the following css line:
border-top: 3px solid black;

what do you mean with slider height change?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dLjw2hkx/) `is a Jsfiddle i made`

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply :), but i didnt get any changes :(
slider height as in to make the picture bigger in my site: http://www.etctaylors.com